# Compare two dates using php and mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I am trying to compare a date with a date in a MySQL database that is either greater than 90, 60, 30 days from the current date.  I'm using the DateTime object and it's been easy to manipulate but I'm having issues getting the response I'm looking for.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
<?php
//date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$todaysDate = new DateTime('now');
$formattedDate = $todaysDate->format('Y-m-d');

$date = new DateTime ('now');
$date90 = $date->add(new DateInterval('P90D'));
$date90 = $date->format('Y-m-d');

$date = new DateTime ('now');
$date60 = $date->add(new DateInterval('P60D'));
$date60 = $date->format('Y-m-d');

$date = new DateTime ('now');
$date30 = $date->add(new DateInterval('P30D'));
$date30 = $date->format('Y-m-d');

//echo $date90;
//echo "<br />";
//echo $formattedDate;

$thirtyDays = array();
$sixtyDays = array();
$ninetyDays = array();


$sql = "SELECT * FROM service;";

if(!$result = $con->query($sql)){
die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');  
}else{              
    //$numRows = $result->num_rows;
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        $boosterDate = $row['boosterDate'];

    }

}

if($boosterDate > $date90){
    echo "greater than 90 days";
    echo "<br />";


}               

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Mysql date-type field for **boosterDate**

Check your mysql database timezone

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

Check your php timezone

```
date_default_timezone_get
```

Make sure they match, if not adjust to match

Comment: `DATETIME` columns are not transformed by the MySQL time zone logic, only `TIMESTAMP` columns.  `DATETIME` columns are non-time-zone aware literals.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot They might be in the wrong time-zone period. It's best to store all data as UTC and convert as required, but not everyone does this.

Comment: MySQL database is system and php timezone is UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the fix you had in mind, but I don't like date-munging in the application when the database handles it so smoothly... you could do the whole thing in SQL.

```
SELECT s.*,
  CASE WHEN DATE(boosterDate) > DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()),INTERVAL 90 DAY) THEN 90
       WHEN DATE(boosterDate) > DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()),INTERVAL 60 DAY) THEN 60
       WHEN DATE(boosterDate) > DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()),INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN 30
       ELSE NULL END AS date_range_test
  FROM service s;
```

This will return the columns from the "service" table plus an extra "date_range_test" column that will contain 90, 60, 30 or NULL.  The first match in a CASE expression wins.  Extra bonus, you can run this query manually and see the output for every row pretty easily.  As written, this truncates everything to midnight on the date prior to comparing.

Comment: Michael,  I really like your solution but I just cannot seem to get it to work.  I created a new column named "boosterWithinDays" and want to change it to 90, 60, or 30 depending if it's within that time frame.  I tried your code exactly and cannot get it to work.    Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I may have been unclear in my example: the "date_range_test" isn't a real column, it's a just a column that will appear in the result set, derived by the query that should populated itself with 30/60/90 or null depending on how far in the future boosterDate is compared to today's date... does the query not work if you run it exactly as it is written (directly in the mysql command line client or wherever you normally run manual queries)?

Comment: I'm sorry Michael.  I need it to check boosterDate and then populate another column boosterWithinDays to either 30, 60, or 90.  I really like the idea of NOT using PHP to do this but I'm having HUGE issues trying to get something so simple to work correctly.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare dates only in DateTime format, but in your case `$boosterDate` is a string. Your code should be looked like:

```
...
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $boosterDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $row['boosterDate'])));

}
...
```

Comment: I would like to use the DateTime object.  Is it possible to take the MySQL date in the format Y-m-d and convert to iso using the DateTime object?  Also, why would the date be stored as a date in MySQL but convert to a string when I run a query?  I'm a little confused by your answer.  Could you please elaborate?